# Need some help with getting my DIV centered

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div id="ftr_btm">
        <div id="ftr_ctr">
            <div class="hdr_lnk">
                <ul>
                <li><a>Test1</a></li>
                <li><a>Test2</a></li>
                <li><a>Test3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
#ftr_ctr {display: block; text-align: center; font-size:0.8em; position: absolute; height: 24px;margin: auto;}
.hdr_lnk ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

What I am trying to do is have the text (address links) appear horizontally centered with margins to each side of the UL's. It's not working and the text and UL's all goes to the left as in this:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JvyNw/)

Is there anyone who could tell me how I can get the UL's to appear in the middle of the page.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of the context that you're putting that code in, but this should achieve the effect you want:

```
#ftr_ctr {
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size:0.8em;
    position: absolute;
    height: 24px;
}

.hdr_lnk ul{
    margin: auto;
}

.hdr_lnk li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The main things you needed were the `width: 100%;` rule in the `#ftr_ctr` element and the `margin: auto;` rule in the `.hdr_lnk ul` rule.  (The width doesn't have to be 100%, but it needed to be set to stop the element from *shrink-wrapping* its contents).  `margin: auto;` will centre contents equally vertically or horizontally or `margin: 0 auto;` will centre contents horizontally.